# ReactCSSTransitionGroup not working with controlled Component

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

I use react transitions when adding message to conversation. It works always when I press send button but when I confirm with 'Enter' it doesnt work for - Opera and Chrome. In Chrome sometimes I get impression that transition happens very very fast.

```
const userMessage = {
    userImage: userImage,
    userName: 'Jason Leapman',
    date: '19:56',
    message: `Agriculture fed larger`

const guestMessage = {
    userImage: guestImage,
    userName: 'Adrian Simon',
    date: '19:56',
    message: `Man's technological ascent`
};

const fakeConversation = [
    userMessage,
    guestMessage,
    guestMessage,
    userMessage,
    guestMessage
];


export default class extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            message: ''
        }
    }


    renderConversation() {
        return fakeConversation.map(
            (message, i) => <Message key={i} message={message}/>
        );
    }

    sendMessage() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const {message} = prevState;
            if (message) {
                const newMessage = Object.assign({}, {...userMessage}, {message});
                fakeConversation.push(newMessage);
                return {message: ''};
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({message: e.target.value});
    }

    onKeyPress(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.sendMessage();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const conversation = this.renderConversation(),
            sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this),
            {message} = this.state,
            onChange = this.onChange.bind(this),
            onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);

        return (
            <Col componentClass="section" xs={12} className="Conversation">
                <div ref={list => this.conversationList = list} className="conversation-list">
                    <FadingTransition>
                        {conversation}
                    </FadingTransition>
                </div>
                <Row className="message-input-row">
                    <Col xs={12}>
                        <MessageInput
                            id="message-input"
                            name="message-input"
                            value={message}
                            onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            onSendClick={sendMessage}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>


            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

FadingTransition:

```
export default ({children, component = 'div', appear = true, enter = true, leave = true}) => (
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        component={component}
        className="FadingTransition"
        transitionName="fading"
        transitionAppear={appear}
        transitionEnter={enter}
        transitionLeave={leave}
        transitionAppearTimeout={100}
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>

        { children }
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
);
```

CSS:

```
.FadingTransition {

    > .fading-enter,
    > .fading-leave {
        margin-left: -200px;
        transition: margin-left .5s ease-out;

        &.fading-enter-active,
        &.fading-leave-active {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    }

    > .fading-appear{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .1s ease-out;

        &.fading-appear-active {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Whats up with this `onKeyPress` am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT:

It helped when I made MessageInput uncontrolled by removing `value` but then I cant clear input after sending message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
.MessageTransition {
    > .fading-enter,
    > .fading-leave {
        margin-left: -200px;

        &.fading-enter-active,
        &.fading-leave-active {
            transition: all .5s ease-out;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    }

    > .fading-appear {
        opacity: 0;

        &.fading-appear-active {
            transition: all .1s ease-out;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I moved the transition property do *-active class.